How to Correct a Docusaurus-Generated Canonical URL That Points to a Redirect?
I'm managing a website built with Docusaurus, and I've encountered an SEO issue where the automatically generated canonical URL points to a redirect. I need advice on how to resolve this problem effectively.
Here's the situation:

Canonical URL: https://resources.instafill.ai/docs/form-tr-205/what-to-include-in-trial-by-written-declaration
HTTP Response: 308 Permanent Redirect
Redirects to: https://resources.instafill.ai/docs/form-tr-205/what-to-include-in-trial-by-written-declaration/ (note the trailing slash)
This leads to a canonical URL that is not the final URL due to the redirect to the URL with a trailing slash. For SEO best practices, it’s essential that the canonical URL is the direct, final URL without any redirects.

Questions:

How can I configure Docusaurus to ensure that the canonical URL aligns directly with the final URL (with or without the trailing slash), avoiding any redirects?
Are there specific configurations or settings in Docusaurus that can be adjusted to prevent this type of issue, especially considering the canonical URL is automatically generated?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue with Docusaurus would be greatly appreciated to ensure optimal SEO performance and avoid indexing issues.

I have the same problem and trailingSlash option solved it:
Allow to customize the presence/absence of a trailing slash at the end of URLs/links, and how static HTML files are generated:

undefined (default): keeps URLs untouched, and emit /docs/myDoc/index.html for /docs/myDoc.md
true: add trailing slashes to URLs/links, and emit /docs/myDoc/index.html for /docs/myDoc.md
false: remove trailing slashes from URLs/links, and emit /docs/myDoc.html for /docs/myDoc.md

https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#trailingSlash

I have fixed my issue by migrating from cloudflare static website hosting to Microsoft azure static websites.

can confirm, had the same issue, solved it by adding trailingSlash: false in docusaurus.config.ts
